# Get all pairs of right-branching words from a sentence

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, python-itertools

Given that I have a string like:

```
 'velvet evening purse bags'
```

how can I get all word pairs of this? In other words, all 2-word combinations of this:

```
'velvet evening'
'velvet purse'
'velvet bags'
'evening purse'
'evening bags'
'purse bags'
```

I know python's `nltk` package can give the bigrams but I'm looking for something beyond that functionality. Or do I have to write my own custom function in Python?

Comment: Assuming that you need bigrams and not just pairs then bigrams need to be pairs of consecutive words. So you would iterate over two iterables, one advanced by a step. Check out `tee` and `zip_longest`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) for this:

```
s = 'velvet evening purse bags'

from nltk import word_tokenize

words = word_tokenize(s)

from itertools import combinations

pairs = [' '.join(comb) for comb in combinations(words, 2)]

print(pairs)
```

Output:

```
['velvet evening', 'velvet purse', 'velvet bags', 'evening purse', 'evening bags', 'purse bags']
```

Comment: just a comment, can also use `word_tokenize` from `nltk`!

Answer (score 1):

This should be interesting =)

If the input is `velvet evening purse bags` and the desired output is what @MrGeek has produced using `itertools.combinations`, that's actually the definition of `skipgrams` from https://tedboy.github.io/nlps/generated/generated/nltk.skipgrams.html

So you can achieve the same with:

```
from nltk import skipgrams

s = 'velvet evening purse bags'
tokens = word_tokenize(s)
list(skipgrams(tokens, n=2, k=len(tokens)-1))
```

[out]:

```
[('velvet', 'evening'),
 ('velvet', 'purse'),
 ('velvet', 'bags'),
 ('evening', 'purse'),
 ('evening', 'bags'),
 ('purse', 'bags')]
```

In this case, **each word can only combine with another word to the right of it**; which somewhat conforms to human English language.

In the case that, all "permutations" of words paired out, even with itself:

```
from itertools import product
s = 'velvet evening purse bags'
tokens = set(word_tokenize(s))
list(product(tokens, tokens))
```

[out]:

```
[('velvet', 'velvet'),
 ('velvet', 'evening'),
 ('velvet', 'purse'),
 ('velvet', 'bags'),
 ('evening', 'velvet'),
 ('evening', 'evening'),
 ('evening', 'purse'),
 ('evening', 'bags'),
 ('purse', 'velvet'),
 ('purse', 'evening'),
 ('purse', 'purse'),
 ('purse', 'bags'),
 ('bags', 'velvet'),
 ('bags', 'evening'),
 ('bags', 'purse'),
 ('bags', 'bags')]
```

Comment: thanks! i really like this answer to complement the marked answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also go old school...

```py
text =  'velvet evening purse bags'

n = []
ans = []
for i in text.split():
    for j in text.split():
        if j != i:
             if (i, j) not in n:
                ans.append((i, j))
                n.append((i, j))
                n.append((j, i))
```

output

```
[('velvet', 'evening'),
 ('velvet', 'purse'),
 ('velvet', 'bags'),
 ('evening', 'purse'),
 ('evening', 'bags'),
 ('purse', 'bags')]
```